# .net 5.0 Core console application inside windows 2012 R2 will raise error "A fatal error occurred.The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dll, asp.net-core-5.0

I have developed a .NET 5.0 console application inside Visual Studio 2019 and it is working well. Then I build the project >> move everything inside the "\bin\Debug\net5.0" to a folder inside Windows server 2012 R2 (Our Live Server) >> but when I run the `.exe` file I got this error :-

```
"A fatal error occurred.The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found"
```

Here is the Full Error:-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd c:\SDSPIntegration

c:\SDSPIntegration>ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration.exe
A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [c:\SDSPIn
tegration\].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global
location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable t
o specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWAR
E\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].

The .NET runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win81
-x64&apphost_version=5.0.4
```

any advice please?

Comment: did you publish it with `--self-contained` flag?

Comment: @yuvin as i mentioned i run the Build the application and move everything inside the `\bin\Debug\net5.0`.. as i do  in .net

Comment: you may want to publish it like this: `dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained`. This should put your build with the entire .NET Core into the publish folder

Comment: otherwise you'll need to install .NET Core on the server

Comment: @yuvin where i should run this command

Comment: @yuvin can you pelase let me know where/how to run this command? `dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 --self-contained`?

Comment: in the console, from the project folder (you can use VS2019 Developer Console, all required PATH's are set up there). Alternatively you can publish the app from Visual Studio (right-click the project > Publish)

Comment: @yuvin ok i publish it as self-contained application.. but now i am getting this error `Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'ServiceDeskSharePointIntegration.Program' threw an exception.
 ---> System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'M' is an invalid escapable characte
r within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 2 |
BytePositionInLine: 46.`

Comment: I suppose it's unrelated to the app publishing. Perhaps you should check the input JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish the program. Please see [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish). You can see there:

> --self-contained [true|false]
>
> Publishes the .NET runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine. Default is true if a runtime identifier is specified and the project is an executable project (not a library project). For more information, see [.NET application publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) and [Publish .NET apps with the .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).